# When is asking questions out of curiosity off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question [Type with a guaranteed size of 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870991/type-with-a-guaranteed-size-of-2) on here and soon got flooded and downvoted by people explaining that they want to see reasoning for my question and apparently I was rude when I pointed out that, in my opinion, one does not need to defend *why* he asked a question.

For the sake of spelling it out, I later added my reasoning: *Pure curiosity*

I understand that there are nonsense questions - where the asker doesn't understand the underlying concept of a topic and thus asks questions that just can't be answered.

In this the case though, the question was quite clear and there is no fundamental misunderstanding of the topic.

> Is there an (possibly optional) integral type with the property >sizeof(mysterious_type) == 2 for whatever system is defined on?

<s>I want to **understand** the reason why several people - apparently - thought that the question is **off-topic or not useful**.</s> I realized this is a bad question to ask, because the answer is quite simple - they dislike the question.

---

After thinking about it some time and to make it more suitable for the [discussion] tag, please add your opinion on

**How to correctly ask a curiosity driven question?**

Comment: The most exciting phrase to hear in science, the one that heralds new discoveries, is not “Eureka” but “That's funny...” — Isaac Asimov

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164436/is-there-a-rule-of-thumb-for-objective-questions-asked-out-of-curiosity

Comment: Of course it's not. I'd say the good number of my questions were posted _out of curiosity_, rather than for solving a practical problem I had.

Comment: As for your question, I also had downvoted it 1st, because your example code was blatantly wrong, and you missed to give a MCVE (which is still missing BTW). You'e asking for a type that's guaranteed to be 2 bytes in size, despite the fact that there may exist systems where `char` doesn't consist from 8 bits, that type is obviously `int16_t`/`uint16_t`. That might be reasons for the downvotes actually.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I'm asking about a type where `sizeof(type) == 2`. That is not 2 bytes, that is `2*sizeof(char)`. Obviously not `int16_t` (as pointed out by @T.C. in the comments and yourself: "systems where char doesn't consist from 8 bits") Then, MCVE for a curiosity question where I don't know if it is possible beforehands? Now how do you expect me to give that?

Comment: @WorldSEnder Also note portability issues regarding endianess, are usually solved by using the `htons()` / `ntohs()` functions family, you don't need to roll your own endianess testing usually. I also remember that there was a compiler intrinsic define value, that can be used.

Comment: This is a meta post, not the question.. go ahead and post that to question

Comment: @WorldSEnder No, I'm trying to explain why it was downvoted, not to answer your question actually.

Comment: @WorldSEnder I tried to give you some reasoning, based on technical background (and that's what we're judgeing you question about in the main site), but it seems that's not what you want to hear (read).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you are right, I should listen to it.. I realize I'm wrong not seeing the reason for the downvotes and I politely ask you if you have an opinion on how to keep such curiosity based questions from being downvoted - or why the downvoting is a nice thing to do.

Comment: @WorldSEnder _"... on how to keep such curiosity based questions from being downvoted ..."_ Well, I can't actually tell. Seem's I were lucky [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861760/what-is-the-actual-purpose-of-stdtype-infoname), and more unlucky [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909598/eliminating-instantiation-of-useless-destructor-calls) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224679/c-static-keyword-vs-c-private-scope) (Uhhh, I'm exposing these on Meta SO now, Ducking :-P ...).

Comment: Trivia questions risk downvotes.  Trivia questions in the C++ tag invite them.  Hell, asking a question in the C++ tag invites downvotes.  I'd suggest you drop it and pick up C#.

Answer (score 13):

SO question should be *useful practical problems*.  If your passing curiosity is something that others would consider useful, and having practical value (even if you're not the one who's putting it to practice) then there's unlikely to be a problem.  If the readers feel that it's not a useful practical problem though, they may choose to downvote the post, as seemed to happen here.

Note that a question not being useful doesn't (in and of itself) mean that meets any of the close criteria, and in your specific case there are no votes to close the question, simply downvotes.

Comment: Now that's the problem: `If your passing curiosity is something that others would consider useful` is a bit vague. One can't know what someone else could develop out of a question from curiosity. And downvoting, imo, states that you believe that the question "has not chance to be useful ever" which is most often simply not true

Comment: @WorldSEnder A downvote states that you don't think the post is useful.  That's what it means.  It is *intentionally* left as a vague description that is open to interpretation.  If you don't want to downvote posts that don't seem useful to you because someone else might possibly find it useful in the future, then I guess that's your choice.  I certainly can't stop you.  Just keep in mind not everyone needs to, or will, vote on posts based on exactly the same interpretation/criteria that you choose to use.

Comment: @WorldSEnder Consider that there are many questions on SO about endianness (your main question) which also show how to check that against a precise number of bytes (subordinate question). That denotes lack of research effort for similar questions which may be source of duplicates and downvotes (there's no usefulness in such duplicate).

Comment: @black, Your practiacal way of thinking is the problem with these kind of questions. You try to solve my problem when I try to find an answer to my question. There are indeed many ways to discover endianess but I added that reasoning after I was "forced" by the comments to come up with a good explaination for my question. As stackexchange foremost a QA board and not a problem solving board, the answer, not the solution is important.

Comment: `As stackexchange is a most impotantly a QA board and not a problem solving board, the answer, not the solution is important.`  You've got that completely backwards.

Comment: @Servy Well that lifts the shadows a bit for me. A feel like asking `Why is stackexchange a problem solving board and not a QA board when all you can do is ask questions and answer questions instead of propose problems and solve problems` but I think that would be a really lengthy title

Comment: @WorldSEnder That's not entirely true. Consider [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378): it does not say you cannot ask "general" question. Just add a bit of background so that you can take out the broadness of it and sort out solutions that will be invalid due to that  context. Also take a look at [this](http://bit.ly/1HPtoQN).

Comment: @Servy That's rare, but I have to [disagree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297058/is-asking-questions-out-of-curiosity-off-topic#comment207619_297058) with you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I didn't say that one can't ever ask a question because you're curious, just that it should be a question that's potentially useful and that has practical value.  If your curious whim has value, then it's fine, if it doesn't (and many don't) then it's not likely to be well received.

Comment: Sorry, reacting on the OP's reaction when trying to give some (technical backgrounded) reasons why their question was downvoted actually, I had to change my mind about your answer (remove the edit as you like).